# Add a hyperlink to a narrative box in an OBIEE Answers 10g Analysis View?

Tags: html, oracle, oracle10g, obiee

How do you add a hyperlink to a narrative box in an OBIEE Answers 10g Analysis View?  I'd like the user to be able to click a link, rather than copying and pasting a text link.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

The answer is to check the 'Contains  HTML Markup' box.

[image]

Then just use the html tag to include a link.

for example,

```
<a href="http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm">Instant SQL Formatter<a/>
```

is rendered as a nice blue clickable link:

[Instant SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)

In Answers it looks like this:

[image]